# Ping a server without freezing the Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I tried to use multiple threads, sadly no luck:

```
public synchronized boolean pingServer(final String ip, final short port) {
    final boolean[] returnbol = new boolean[1];
    Thread tt = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Socket s = new Socket(ip, port);
                s.close();
                returnbol[0] = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                returnbol[0] = false;
            }
        }
    });
    tt.start();
    try {
        tt.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        tt.stop();
    }
    tt.stop();
    return returnbol[0];
}
```

The main thread still Freezes for some reason.

**Is there a "lagless" way to ping a server?**

Comment: What do you think `tt.join()` does?

Comment: You're making the current thread waiting until `tt` finishes its execution.

Comment: @Reimeus I was mislead by user telling me that tt.join(); wait's till the tasks gets finished.

Comment: Why start a thread to do something if you're just going to wait for it to finish? Instead of waiting, just do it yourself. What does the thread gain you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What exactly did you want to got in

```
try {
        tt.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        tt.stop();
    }
```

block?
Here you joined to parallel thread and waits till this thread will ends (got ping result).

You have next options:

- Wait till ping ends
- Don't wait... and don't got result
- Use some concurrency classes like Future<> to got result (but you will block thread at moment you ask result if it not retrieved yet)
- Or you can use some 'callback' function/interface to threw result from inner 'ping' thread.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to remove the following lines from your code.
The tt.join() will force the main thread to wait for tt to finish.

```
try {
    tt.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    tt.stop();
}
tt.stop();
```

Use a Future instead to get the result for later use